# Show that $F=\{f\in C([0,1]):f(s)\ge 0,\; \forall s\in[0,1]\}$ is closed in $\left(C([0,1]), d_{\infty}\right)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I start by considering the complement
$$F^c = \{f\in C([0,1]): f(s) < 0, \textrm{for some } s\in[0,1]\}$$
and I want to show that for every $f\in F^c$ the open ball $B(f,r)\subset F^c$ for some positive $r>0$ i.e the set $F^c$ is open in $\left(C([0,1]), d_{\infty}\right)$, where $d_{\infty}$ denotes the
max-metric $d_{\infty}(f,g) =\max_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)-g(t)|$

I pick $g\in B(f,r)$ so by definition we have that $d_{\infty}(f,g)
< r$. This means also that
$$|f(s)-g(s)| \le \max_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)-g(t)| < r$$

where $s\in[0,1]$ is fixed s.t $f(s)<0$.Because
$$g(s)-f(s) \le |g(s)-f(s)| = |f(s)-g(s)| < r$$

we can for example choose $r = \frac{f(s)}{2}$ which means that

$$g(s) < f(s) + r < \frac{3}{2}f(s) < 0$$

for some $s\in[0,1]$. So we have that $B(f,r)\subset F^c$ and therefore $F^c$ must be closed.

I'm rather uncertain about my proof in general and would like to receive suggestions if it isn't correct

Comment: It's quite fine, only a comment: $f(s) < 0$ so you can't take $r = \frac{f(s)}{2}$, instead you can pick $r = \frac{|f(s)|}{2}$.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot @BrianBritosSimmari

Comment: And of course, the negative upper bound you get is not $\frac32f(s)$ but $\frac12f(s).$ A less pedestrian proof would be: $F$ is the intersection of the (closed!) subsets $\phi_s^{-1}([0,+\infty)),$ where for every $s\in[0,1],$ $\phi_s:C([0,1])\to\Bbb R$ is the (continuous!) linear functional $f\mapsto f(s).$